# CiviCRM Events (WP) - error message "this contact has already been assigned to this event"

Tags: civievent

Getting the error message "civicrm error message Please correct the following errors in the form fields below: This contact has already been assigned to this event."

Oddly, this record is my own. I'm wondering if it's BECAUSE I created the event that I can't add myself. I am the Civi admin.

My name doesn't come up in any registered attendee report and when searching my own record, I am not recorded as being registered to the event. But I can't add myself, either. See below.

[image]

Here's what it looks like when I try to add:

[image]

So, I'm stumped! It's not life or death, but insights are appreciated in the event it crops up with other contacts as this event progresses. If it crops up with another contact, that could affect the event headcount.

Thanks,

L.

Comment: Any chance you did a 'test' registration? (you can search for 'test' via Find Participants) If you did, i don't see why it should block you from registering again but something is obviously odd. If you have access to the db, check the participant table for your contact id.

Comment: Doh! I did! I found the test and deleted it. Now I can add myself!

Comment: Forgot to add the Thanks. Sooo... Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok. let me add as an answer so you can accept and help close this off for SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be the outcome if you did a 'test' registration.

You can search for 'test' via Find Participants.

If you did, it is possible this would block you from registering again.